# How to pipe output of a command that expects file argument

Tags: shell, file, pipe, command-line-interface, io-redirection

I know you can pipe output of a one command to another - for example

```
ls -la | less
```

to see output of `ls -la` inside of `less` instead of terminal stdio.

But if you use a `command` with a parameter that saves the output to a file

```
command --save-to-file file.txt
```

Then how to pipe that to another command?

this way will not work:

```
command --save-to-file | less
```

because command will complain that you used `--save-to-file` without any argument (filename)

If I remember well there was something like a buffer or a temp file in ram you could put instead of `file.txt` so you could do something like:

```
command --save-to-file ram-buffer.txt && cat ram-buffer.txt
```

Without even creating a file on disk, it that right?

Why I need that?

Some of commands have only a basic output to the stdio and more useful type of output cannot be printed by them but only saved to file. The thing is I am not interested in saving the more useful type of output to any file at all but just to print it in terminal or pipe to chain of another commands that do the filtering etc and then eventually print the processed output.

I would not like to be responsible to crating a tmp file then delete it etc. Perfectly I would like to just use a kind of magic file (or redirection) in place of `file.txt` that I could pipe to another command.

It is important to me to not write any content of the output to a disk if this is possible. Just print it in terminal or pipe to other command(s).

At this moment I'm trying to capture output of PHPUnit

```
phpunit --log-junit log.xml
```

which is not a shell command but a PHP script that uses:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

But I remember I used to have an example with linux command that I wanted get the output but the form of it was only available with a parameter `--save-to-file outputfile.txt`

Perhaps because piping/redirecting an output designed to be saved to a file is not binary safe and therefore such output can be corrupted when piped/redirected - can it be?

Comment: Do you have an example of a command that divulges the extra information only when printing to a file? What's the exact syntax, is it something like `cmd -f output.txt`, or just `cmd --save-to-file` without an argument?

Comment: @BenjaminW. `cmd --save-to-file output.txt` I've put more info with the edit of the question.

Comment: In Bash, you could write to the pseudo-file `/dev/stdout` instead of `output.txt`.

Comment: If the command in question does not have an easy, intutitive (and indeed default) mechanism for writing to stdout, the first step is to submit a bug report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some programs have special handling for `-`. For example, you can tell `tar` to write to stdout so it can be used in a pipeline. This would create a tarball locally and untar it remotely without the tarball ever being written to disk:

```
tar -cf - *.txt | ssh user@host tar -C /dir/ -xf -
```

You can use `/dev/stdout` with nearly all programs, as long as they don't need a seekable file.

```
command --save-to-file /dev/stdout
```

Comment: `command --save-to-file /dev/stdout` did the job. I used exactly: `phpunit --stderr --log-junit /dev/stdout | tail +3 | less` with `tail +3` to get the xml content because PHPUnit complained at the beginning of file "Warning: fopen(/dev/stdout): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ..." but after that it gave me exactly what I wanted to get without writing to any file.

Answer (score 1):

As @Benjamin W. pointed out in the comments, you can save it to `/dev/stdout`, which is the output and then pipe the output to whatever you want(e.g. less)

```
command --save-to-file /dev/stdout | less
```

Take care because there may be additional output to stdout. In this case you could throw that away, save it to `stderr` and redirect it to `stdout`:

command --save-to-file /dev/stderr >/dev/null 2>/dev/stdout | less

If both, `stderr` and `stdout` are used you may be able to write your own driver for this of manipulate `/proc/pid/mem` or something like this.